# "Humanities studies is my zone of interest." Is that sentence natural?

Tags: grammar, expressions, phrasing

"Humanities studies is my zone of interest." Is that sentence natural?

I want to express that I love anything related to the humanities division.

- Should I use "is" or "are"?
- Is there such an expression as "zone of interest"?
- In the phrasing of the title of my question, should I have said "THIS sentence" instead of "THAT sentence"?

Sorry for the tremendous amount of questions :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression 'zone of interest' isn't used.

Consider using instead 'area' or 'field of interest'.

One would use THAT sentence if there is both a THIS and THAT sentence. If there is just a single sentence you are referting to, then THIS sentence is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

1. It should be 'are' as 'studies' is plural.
2. 'Field of interest' is a more appropriate phrase.
3. 'This sentence' is accurate because you are referring to the previous sentence itself. 'This' implies closeness.

Comment: Thank you, @Sid !